# What does the error " bad operand types for binary operator '&&' " mean in java program?

Tags: java

I get in next code:

```
class Divisible {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int number[]=new int[200];
        int i,sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<number.length;i++) {
            number[i]=i;
        }
        for(i=0;i<number.length;i++) {
            if((number[i]>100) && (number[i]<200) && (number[i]/7)) {
                sum=sum+number[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum =" +sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `number[i]/7` doesn't return a boolean. Perhaps you meant to write `number[i]%7==0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite clear - && is a binary operator and you need to use a boolean operand for it.

Here:

```
if((number[i]>100) && (number[i]<200) && (number[i]/7))
```

`(number[i]/7)` is a number, and it does not qualify to be an operand of && operator.

Comment: what corrections needs to be done?

Comment: @CHAMP3333 Do you need to check if the number is divisible by 7?

Comment: @CHAMP3333 In that case, you can do : `&& (number[i]%7==0)`

Comment: it worked....thankyou so much@Hackerdarshi